# is running django syncdb in production, post initial deployment safe?

Tags: django, django-syncdb

I read somewhere that you would never run `syncdb` on a database, post its initial run.
Is this true?

I don't see what the problem could be. Do you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

running `syncdb` will not make changes to tables for any models already in the database (even if you have changed them).

for managing changes to models, consider [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)

Comment: This is without mentioning `syncdb` also reload all `initial_data` fixtures at each call, unless `--no-initial-data` specified (available since django1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Syncdb will create tables that don't exist, but not modify existing tables.  So it's fairly safe to run in production.  But it's not a reliable way to maintain a database schema.  Look at the [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) package for a way to reliably maintain changes to your database schema between development and production.  Should be part of django standard, IMHO.